# Disabling translations in Tomcat 7

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

Tomcat 7 seems to automatically translate response status code headers into various languages based on the response locale and if the language bundle jar is installed in the tomcat/lib directory.

I am surprised that Tomcat would do this, response headers are recommended to be ASCII only as far as I understand. I do not see the value in translating this.

Is there a configuration option for Tomcat to disable this feature? It is causing some issues with a proxy I am using.

I know I can fix it by removing the language bundle from the install. Is that the recommended/only approach?

Thank you.